# Change the order of List items conditionally with LINQ

Tags: c#, linq

i'm getting a list of items with following LINQ expression,

```
var list = (from p in listData
            orderby p.Code ascending
            select new KeyValuePair<int, string>(p.Code, p.DESC)
            ).Distinct<KeyValuePair<int, string>>().ToList<KeyValuePair<int, string>>();
```

i'm getting the list as,

```
2,MEDICAL
5,RETAIL
6,OTHER
7,GOVT
```

ordered by `Code`

now, my expected result is as below,

```
2,MEDICAL
5,RETAIL
7,GOVT
6,OTHER
```

i know that i can get the expected result either by modifying the `sql table` containing these values or by adding an extra numeric `column` to the table specifying the sequence order.

is it possible to get the results with the help of `LINQ` without modifying the table?

Comment: i want to show values in the specified order inside dropdown list

Answer (score 10, accepted):

So you want `OTHER` to be at the last position?

```
from p in listData
orderby p.DESC == "OTHER" ascending, p.Code ascending
```

This works because `true` is "higher" than `false`, maybe you find this more readable:

```
orderby p.DESC == "OTHER"  ? 1 : 0 ascending
```

Comment: thanks a lot..it worked..but still i'm not able to understand the logic behind it

Comment: @user3085995: This is similar to SQL. So multiple sort columns can be specified. The result set is sorted by the first column and then that ordered list is sorted by the second column, and so on. In this case the highest priority has the comparison `p.DESC == "OTHER"` which returns `true` or `false`. So you get two groups, these groups are ordered by the second column `p.Code` then. On this way you get first all which `DESC` is not "OTHER", then all ordered by `Code`.